# Google reCAPTCHA v3: can't submit the form in data-callback

Tags: recaptcha

When I click the "submit" button, the form is not submitted. Why?

I got it straight from Google's sample code, all I added was one line:

document.getElementById("myform").submit();

The "thanks" message was shown.

If I click the "submit without validate" button, the form is submitted.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('name').value);
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }

    function validate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!document.getElementById('name').value) {
            alert("You must add text to the required field");
        } else {
            grecaptcha.execute();
        }
    }

    function onload() {
        var element = document.getElementById('submit');
        element.onclick = validate;
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Second/Save" method="post" id="myform">
    Name: (required) <input id="name" name="name">

    <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
         data-sitekey="6LexWMMZAAAAAGpLECkk-pfZ-sYuQ9qDu7wiMJ3M"
         data-callback="onSubmit"
         data-size="invisible"></div>

    <button id='submit'>submit</button>
    <button onclick="onSubmit();">Submit Without Validate</button>
</form>
<script>onload();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have a button in the form with the id "submit". Any element in the form with a name or an id is reflected in a form attribute with that name. So if you have  the form object will have an "elephants" attribute. In this case the submit button is accessible via form.submit, but this masks the submit() function.

> If a form control (such as a submit button) has a name or id of submit, this method will mask the form's submit method.

[MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your site key, this error is mainly formed when your domain does not match your site key.

You can create your own google captcha key of your domain with your google account it's free of cost from the link given below
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Comment: The site key has no problem. If I use a wrong key, the onSubmit wouldn't be called. But now it is called. It is just the "document.getElementById("myform").submit();" is skipped somehow.

Comment: This was my problem because I didn't consider I was testing from localhost.